# How to prove $n=7k$ or $7k+1$, if $n=x^2=y^3$.

Tags: induction

$n$ is both a square and a cube, I need to prove $n=7k$ or $n=7k+1$, for some integer $k$.

I need some guide lines.

Comment: What remainders can a square have upon division by $7$, and what remainders a cube?

Comment: I don't think induction will help you here. Check all of the possible values of $x^2$ and $x^3$ modulo 7, as Daniel suggests.

Comment: This is to prove $n^6 = 7k$ or $n^6 = 7k + 1$. Look up [Fermat's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

Answer (score 7):

A number is a square and a cube iff it is a sixth power. According to Fermat's litte theorem, $z^6\equiv 1\pmod 7$ if $z\not\equiv 0\pmod 7$.

Answer (score 6):

If $n$ is both a square and a cube, it is a perfect $6$-th power.

Let $z$ be a number. Then $z$ has shape $7k$, or $7k+1$, or $7k+2$, and so on up to $7k+6$.

Then $z^6$ has shape (respectively) $7k$, $7k+1$, $7k+1$, $7k+1$, $7k+1$, $7k+1$, and $7k+1$.

To do the calculations, let us take the example $z$ of the shape $7k+2$.

Imagine expanding $(7k+2)^6$ using the Binomial Theorem. The first $6$ terms are obviously divisible by $7$, and the last term is $2^6=64$. This has remainder $1$ on division by $7$. So $(7k+2)^6$ has remainder $1$ on division by $7$, and therefore has shape $7t+1$.

The other calculations are very similar.

**Remark:** We do not need to work with $6$-th powers. The squares of numbers of shape $7k+a$, where $a$ goes from $0$ to $6$, are, in order, of shape
$$7k \qquad 7k+1 \qquad 7k+4 \qquad 7k+2\qquad 7k+2 \qquad 7k+4\qquad 7k+1.$$
The cubes, are, in order,  of the shape
$$7k \qquad 7k+1 \qquad 7k+1 \qquad 7k+6\qquad 7k+1 \qquad 7k+6\qquad 7k+6.$$
Only $7k$ and $7k+1$ occur in both lists.

Answer (score 1):

Observe that:

Any square modulo 7 will be one of the following:
$$0, 1, 4, 2$$ 
Any cube modulo 7 will be one of the following:
$$0, 1, 6$$